# How to draw PNG over dialog controls

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, window, gdi+

I need to make some thing like a SEMI-transparent glass layer over dialog's controls. The context is when my application wait for a long process to finish all other controls need to be disabled, and an animation is shown on glass layer as waiting-animation.

I am going to draw a semi-transparent PNG image with size of client area, overlapping all other controls. I do the drawing in OnPaint() but image is drawn as background of the dialog.

So my question is how can i draw png image overlap dialog's control??

LRs

Comment: Never draw directly on top of a dialog, or other controls. Add a STATIC control to your dialog and draw on top of that, instead.

Comment: Thank for reply. You mean i put a static overlapped all others control, and draw a png image on the static?. By doing it so, can i get semi-transparent effect by which i can see other controls?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with fiddling the WS_CLIPCHILDREN and WS_CLIPSIBLINGS styles, but I'm not sure that will work. I think you will need to draw a custom control on top of all other controls (at the top of the z-order stack) and draw your bitmap on that one (that's the approach I would take - the dialog is supposed to be behind the controls always, so your approach of drawing on the dialog is fighting the system, as it were).

So basically you would draw on the custom control that would cover all other controls, but you don't even need to draw it transparently; you can use the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT and/or WS_EX_LAYERED window style and SetLayeredWindowAttributes() method, as long as you don't need to support operating systems older than win2k.

Comment: I will try you solution to see how it works, thank alot for your help.